# What is the best way to guarantee that the person I send an image to from my iPhone 10 receives it in full quality?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I have an [iPhone X](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP770?locale=en_US) and I want to send high quality photos to someone using another device I don’t know.

I’m taking photos in HEIF 12 megapixel format.

To maximize the quality of the photo received by the other does it work best to send photos through text message Facebook Messenger or email?

Comment: Can you define a bit full quality? I’ll edit some specifics in the body, but iPhone 10 runs quite a few versions of iOS and the photo format changes a bit each release. Can we assume your recipient is in the exact same iPhone 10 and iOS?

Answer (score 2):

Pending on sensitivity of photos and privacy preferences one can use iCloud link instead of attaching file to e-mail (or sending using messaging app). iCloud Mail will use iCloud link for files over 20 MB anyway.

iCloud links expire automatically after 30 days (you can stop sharing manually whenever you like) and anyone with the link can view them. More information in Apple support document: [Share photos and videos on iCloud.com](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/share-photos-and-videos-mm93a9b98683/icloud)

Comment: This is the best way if you can’t control who is receiving them. For windows and android users, they can download the best version of our photos even if they don’t have HEIF capability. For Apple devices, this also is most likely to “just work” as it won’t run into attachment size limits or be re-sampled for SMS

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be sending the images via email.

Most messaging apps may compress the images. However, email treats the images as just plain attachment.

However, you may be restricted by a file size limit when sending via email.